# IP address with Port value Not getting in cakephp 2.0 Method

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Am using a Method to get Ip address and other related values in cakephp 2.0, When i pass the IP address value without Port the method is getting the value as shown below.

Query sttring : `http://20.0.1.11/emc-3.4/admin/devices/deviceData/PM8/20.0.1.8/admin/password/public`

Method :

```
public function admin_deviceData($modelName =  null,$ip=null,$username=null,$password=null,$community = "public") {
    echo "$ip";
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Output: `20.0.1.8`

But If query I pass the query String value with Port in IP address am not getting the value in the method.

`http://20.0.1.11/emc-3.4/admin/devices/deviceData/PM8/20.0.1.8:9006/admin/password/public`

Method :

```
public function admin_deviceData($modelName =  null,$ip=null,$username=null,$password=null,$community = "public") {
    echo "$ip";
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Output: `admin`

Comment: Cakephp doesn't pass paramms continaing a colon `:` as an argument to functions, they are stored at `$this->request->params['named']` and not in  `$this->request->params['pass']`

Comment: is there any possible way to change the configuration to accept : in argument values?

Comment: I dont think so! try using another sign instead of colon, semicolon or underscore for example

Comment: I already used hyphen to fix the issue. But looking for a Proper solutions.

Comment: i recommand you to post that in http://discourse.cakephp.org/, you may find the solution there